# Cavalier King Charles Spaniel

Tags: british-english

I can't understand what the phrase "Cavalier King Charles Spaniel" means. Perhaps it means "a spaniel  which belongs to the knight (or cavalier) King Charles". Please, help!

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate,  but you should read the help center to learn what you need to put into a good question. In this case, you should start with some research such as in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalier_King_Charles_Spaniel

Answer (score 1):

A Cavalier King Charles Spaniel is a breed of dog, descended from the King Charles Spaniel.

> Charles II of England was very fond of the toy spaniel, which is why the dogs now carry his name

[Wikipedia 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Charles_Spaniel#17th_century_and_Charles_II)

> 'Cavalier' was first used by Roundheads as a term of abuse for the wealthier Royalist supporters of King Charles I

[Wikipedia 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalier)